# What is a word for a person who find it okay to hurt himself if it can help someone he know

Tags: single-word-requests

I haven't seen any person like that in real life but I have seen a show where a Person is like that so I want to know if there's a word fir that.

Comment: A [**long-suffering**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/long-suffering) person, perhaps.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Answer (score 4):

If your behaviour or motives are ***[altruistic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/altruistic)***, you show concern for the happiness and welfare of other people even if it results in disadvantage for yourself.

I might call them *selfless*.

> **Selfless:** If you say that someone is selfless, you approve of them because they care about other people more than themselves.
> [[**Collins Dictionary**]](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/selfless)

Or they're *self-sacrificing*.

> **Self-sacrificing:** Sacrifice of oneself or one's interest for others or for a cause or ideal.
> **[[M-W]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-sacrifice)**